# Calling generic function with Functor using subclass (cats/scalaz)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, scalaz, scala-cats

I've been messing around with some basic examples of Cats/Scalaz and also walking through tutorials to get a feel and I've hit a case which I'm sure there is a solution to.

Is it possible to call a generalized function that takes a contextualized value (`F[A]`) with a Functor view (`F[_] : Functor`) with a context that is `<: F`? I'm aware that Functor is invariant on type `F[_]`, and I'm also aware of the existence of `Functor.widen`, but it seems strange that there is no way to implicitly widen my type for use in a general function.

An example in Cats (a similar example with Scalaz exists as well):

```
import cats.instances.all._
import cats.syntax.all._

def takesAFunctor[F[_] : cats.Functor](f: F[Int]) = f.map(_ + 1)

takesAFunctor(Option(1)) // Works fine (of course)
takesAFunctor(Some(1)) // No implicit for Functor[Some]. Makes sense, but can we summon one since we have a Functor[Option]?
takesAFunctor(Some(1): Option[Int]) // Works but very verbose
```

Of course, summoning the Functor for Option explicitly and mapping works as expected

```
Functor[Option].map(Some(1))(_ + 1) // Some(2)
```

So my question is: Does the signature of the general function need to change to account for the subclassed context, is there some sort of "implicit widening" that I don't know about, or is this just an unfortunate drawback to functional programming in Scala using the stdlib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't generally possible as Dmytro's answer points out. This is the reason that cats/scalaz exposes a `.some` extension method that is typed as returning `Option`, whereas using the `Some` constructor returns `Some`;

`takesAFunctor(1.some)`

Alternately you can use the more general `Apply` syntax; `takesAFunctor(1.pure[Option])`

> is there some sort of "implicit widening" that I don't know about, or is this just an unfortunate drawback to functional programming in Scala using the stdlib?

The implicit widening you see when summoning the Option functor manually is covariance. The instance is defined invariantly for `Option` which is why `Some` isn't acceptable - the compiler can't find the implicit, but `Functor[Option].map` expects an `Option` or any subtype of `Option`, which is why Some works.

The drawback that you mention here is basically an impedance mismatch between the java-ish covariant subtyping and the more haskell-ish invariantly typed typeclasses

Comment: A-ha! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I completely neglected to take Function variance into account, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> // No implicit for Functor[Some]. 
> // Makes sense, but can we summon one since we have a Functor[Option]?
> ```

How would you define such instance in general case?

```
  implicit def subtypeFunctor[F[_], G[T] <: F[T]](implicit functor: Functor[F]): Functor[G] = new Functor[G] {
    override def map[A, B](ga: G[A])(f: A => B): G[B] = functor.map(ga)(f)
  }
```

doesn't work since `functor.map(ga)(f)` is generally of type `F[B]` and not necessarily `G[B]`.

So generally no, it's impossible to derive functor for subtype constructor and reasons are fundamental.

[Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Definition) `F` maps objects `T` to objects `F[T]` and morphisms `f: A => B` to morphisms `map(f): F[A] => F[B]` (plus some laws). `F` in `F[B]` is in covariant position and `F` in `F[A]` is in contravariant position, so the only option for functor type class is to be invariant in type constructor.

By the way, you can also call `takesAFunctor` as `takesAFunctor[Option](Some(1))`.

Comment: This is a great breakdown, thank you. I think I understand the concept behind why Functor is invariant on its context now, which definitely helps explain why everything I was trying wasn't working!