# Why can find `Functor` instance for Tree but not for Branch or Leaf?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, invariance

I have the following Functor definition:

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor._

object Theory {

  implicit val treeFunctor: Functor[Tree] =
    new Functor[Tree] {
      def map[A, B](fa: Tree[A])(f: A => B): Tree[B] =
        fa match {
          case Branch(left, right) =>
            Branch(map(left)(f), map(right)(f))
          case Leaf(value) =>
            Leaf(f(value))
        }
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
  }


}
```

for:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]

final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
```

Why the compiler complains:

```
// <console>:42: error: value map is not a member of wrapper.Branch[
Int]
//
Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
//
```

So I have to create a smart constructor:

```
object Tree {
  def branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]): Tree[A] =
    Branch(left, right)
  def leaf[A](value: A): Tree[A] =
    Leaf(value)
}
```

What is a smart constructor in this case?

Comment: Use defined functor for `Tree` not for `Branch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of `Functor[F[_]]` in `cats` is invariant in `F`.
Therefore, a `Functor[Tree]` is neither a generalization, nor a specialization of `Functor[Branch]`. These types are unrelated.

The problem with your code is the following. The expression

```
Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20))
```

is of type `Branch[Int]`. When you try to apply `.map[X]` to it directly, you signal that you would like to get a `Branch[X]` as the result. But there is no `Functor[Branch]` in scope (it's not like you couldn't write one, but as it stands, there is none).

In order to make use of the `Functor[Tree]`, you have to make it clear to the compiler that you want to treat this instance as `Tree[Int]`. Casting would work. Or using a custom factory method that hides `Branch` and exposes `Tree` would work too: that's what the "smart" constructor is doing.

Comment: I'll just add that `Functor[F[_]]` is invariant in `F` not just in `cats`, it's simply invariant in `F`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181109/calling-generic-function-with-functor-using-subclass-cats-scalaz

Comment: @DmytroMitin Hmm... *thinking*: It takes `F[A], A => B`, returns `F[B]`... takes `F`, returns `F`... */thinking* Oh yes, indeed! You're absolutely right! I think there was some discussion about whether `F[+_]` could be made covariant, but this is also not the case. So, yes, remark accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kittens` and implement instances for `Branch` and `Leaf`, then the instance for `Tree` can be derived.

`libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "kittens" % "1.0.0-RC2"`

```
  import cats.Functor
  import cats.syntax.functor._

  sealed trait Tree[+A]
  final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
  final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]

  implicit val treeFunctor: Functor[Tree] = cats.derive.functor[Tree]

  implicit val branchFunctor: Functor[Branch] =
    new Functor[Branch] {
      def map[A, B](fa: Branch[A])(f: A => B): Branch[B] =
        fa match {
          case Branch(left, right) =>
            Branch(left.map(f), right.map(f))
        }
    }

    // or without extension method
//  implicit def branchFunctor(implicit treeFunctor: Functor[Tree]): Functor[Branch] =
//    new Functor[Branch] {
//      def map[A, B](fa: Branch[A])(f: A => B): Branch[B] =
//        fa match {
//          case Branch(left, right) =>
//            Branch(treeFunctor.map(left)(f), treeFunctor.map(right)(f))
//        }
//    }

  implicit val leafFunctor: Functor[Leaf] =
    new Functor[Leaf] {
      def map[A, B](fa: Leaf[A])(f: A => B): Leaf[B] =
        fa match {
          case Leaf(value) =>
            Leaf(f(value))
        }
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)): Tree[Int]).map(_ * 2)
    Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
    Leaf(10).map(_ * 2)
  }
```

---

Actually then you can derive all three instances:

```
  implicit val treeFunctor: Functor[Tree] = cats.derive.functor[Tree]
  implicit val leafFunctor: Functor[Leaf] = cats.derive.functor[Leaf]
  implicit val branchFunctor: Functor[Branch] = cats.derive.functor[Branch]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)): Tree[Int]).map(_ * 2)
    Branch(Leaf(10), Leaf(20)).map(_ * 2)
    Leaf(10).map(_ * 2)
  }
```