# Cats instances for Some and None et al

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-cats, subtyping

In Scala 2.13 and Cats, the following works fine:

```
import cats.implicits._
Traverse[Option]
```

However the following fails:

```
import cats.implicits._
Traverse[Some]
```

I would like for the latter to work, not only for Traverse of Option subclasses, but for any type that has a parent that there exists a given typeclass for.

I have tried creating a method with implicit proof <:< but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: **cats** does not have those, and you should never need them. The very fact that `Some` exists as a type is a bad consequence of the _OOP_ parts of the language. Care to explain why would you want those?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually this is not necessarily because of OOP. In Haskell (`data Option a = Some a | None`) `Some` and `None` are not types. But with language extension "data kinds" switched on they are (type-level programming) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558648/what-is-the-datakinds-extension-of-haskell

Comment: @DmytroMitin Interesting, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really understand what you do you can define necessary instance manually (when it exists).

`Some` is isomorphic to `Id`.

```
implicit val someTraverse: Traverse[Some] = new Traverse[Some] {
  override def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, A, B](fa: Some[A])(f: A => G[B]): G[Some[B]] = f(fa.value).map(Some(_))
  override def foldLeft[A, B](fa: Some[A], b: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = f(b, fa.value)
  override def foldRight[A, B](fa: Some[A], lb: Eval[B])(f: (A, Eval[B]) => Eval[B]): Eval[B] = f(fa.value, lb)
}
```

Generally this is not possible. If `F` is a functor and `G[T] <: F[T]` for all `T` then `G` is not necessarily a functor.

[Calling generic function with Functor using subclass (cats/scalaz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181109/calling-generic-function-with-functor-using-subclass-cats-scalaz/)

Also sometimes you can *derive* type classes using [kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens).

[Why can find `Functor` instance for Tree but not for Branch or Leaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545028/why-can-find-functor-instance-for-tree-but-not-for-branch-or-leaf/)