# Can I get the compiler to realize there is an Applicative for the superclass?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, applicative

I've got a trait which has an implicit `cats.Applicative`, and I have a case class which implements that trait. I want to be able to call methods from `cats.syntax.apply` on tuples of that case class, but the compiler doesn't realize it needs to go looking for the Applicative for the *trait*, and instead fails while trying to look for the Applicative for the *case class*.

For example: (note this is not my actual class, just a distillation of the problem)

```scala
import cats.arrow.FunctionK
import cats.Applicative
import cats.syntax.apply._

// The trait
trait GenericLookup[+A] {
  def get(map: FunctionK[Key, Option]): Option[A]
}
object GenericLookup {
  implicit val applicative: Applicative[GenericLookup] = /* ... */
}

// The subclass
case class Key[A](keyword: String) extends GenericLookup[A] {
  def get(map: FunctionK[Key, Option]) = map(this)
}

// Some instances
val Foo = Key[String]("foo")
val Bar = Key[Boolean]("bar")
val Age = Key[Int]("age")
```

I want to be able to do e.g. `(Foo, Bar, Age).tupled` to get a `GenericLookup[(String, Boolean, Int)]`, or call `(Foo, Bar, Age).mapN { /* ... */ }` to get a `GenericLookup[Whatever]`. But:

```scala
val fba = (Foo, Bar, Age).tupled
// could not find implicit value for parameter invariant: cats.Invariant[Key]
```

It wants to find a typeclass for `Key`, whereas *I* want it to find the typeclass for `GenericLookup`.

The best thing I've come up with so far is to add

```scala
def generic: GenericLookup[A] = this
```

to the `Key` class, which lets me do

```scala
(Foo.generic, Bar, Age).tupled
```

which seems to convince the compiler to go find the typeclass for GenericLookup instead of Key...

Is there a more automatic way I could set things up that would allow the use of `(Foo, Bar, Age).tupled` without having to add extra operators or syntax?

Comment: I doubt it can work, this is basically the same reason why there are not instances for `Some` and `None` only for `Option`. I would guess the best you can do is have a trait that the companions of each subtype of `GenericLookup` can inherit and automatically get an instance of `Applicative` for that. - Another one, maybe to do something like `implicit def applicative[F[x] <: GenericLookup[x]]: Applicative[F] = ...`

Comment: Unfortunate, but expected. Thanks for your comment. Sadly, for my use-case I can't define an `Applicative[Key]` (even using that `F[x] <: G[x]` approach) due to the actual class having special semantics around being a "single" thing, so I guess I'm stuck with the "down-cast" approach.

Comment: The problem with the downcast is that then `tupled` returned a `GenericLookup` instead of `Key` which I assume is not what you want and then you would need to cast with `asInstanceOf` - I wonder why the `trait` doesn't work?

Comment: Actually it _is_ what I want. I mentioned special semantics on the Key type so I _don't_ want an `Applicative[Key]` to be defined, since for my particular use-case, combining multiple Keys together _should_ result in a `GenericLookup` instead of a `Key`. If it weren't for that, I probably would not have split it up this way in the first place.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense and yeah the upcast seems like the best option just like **cats** provides the smart constructors `foo.some` and `none[Bar]` to get better type inference. - Having said that, I wonder if this is _"fixable"_ in **Scala 3**? An automatic upcast doesn't sound like a bad idea in the general sense but maybe I am being too naive. Nevertheless, I think it would be worth raising this on the contributors **Discourse**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181109/calling-generic-function-with-functor-using-subclass-cats-scalaz

Comment: @Dylan In `def ap[A, B](ff: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B]` `F` in `F[A => B]` and `F[A]` is in a contravariant position while in `F[B]` it's in a covariant position. So the only option for `F` is to be invariant. That's the reason why it's `Applicative[F[_]]` and not `Applicative[+F[_]]` or `Applicative[-F[_]]`. So generally there is no way to derive `Applicative` for a subtype or supertype if there is an instance for `F`.

Comment: @Dylan *"I can't define an `Applicative[Key]` (even using that `F[x] <: G[x]` approach) due to the actual class having special semantics around being a "single" thing"* Just curious, what does this mean

Comment: @DmytroMitin it's related to the business logic. A `Key` represents a field to eventually be displayed in the UI, and so it has a variety of methods that only make sense for a single field (like `asTextInput` which returns a text field builder). If I combine two keys, those methods no longer make sense, therefore an `Applicative[Key]` doesn't make sense. Whereas `GenericLookup` is more concerned with interpreting values from a submitted form.

Comment: If you don't need to use `Key` type directly you can define `def key[A](name: String): GenericLookup[A] = Key(name)` and use it like `x.some` or `none` from @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez example from Cats.